# Why does webpack-dev-server infinitely reload?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I forked (not ejected) Create React App 5 and have modified it slightly to fit my application: I change `PUBLIC_URL` to be `file://build/` (I have an Electron app that loads a HTML file using `file://` but that shouldn't make any difference).

When I do this, when I edit a file while webpack-dev-server 5 is running, webpack 5's Hot Module Replacement infinitely reloads the window instead of just reloading the window once.

I looked into the sourcecode for HMR and when the webpack-dev-server client loads it gets the current hash of the bundle, then HMR tells the client about a new hash, it then does a comparison and if it's different, it triggers either a HMR replacement or a full page reload (which happens to me because it's my `src/index` file).

For some reason the initial hash is never updated to the new hash so when it does the comparison it always fails, so infinitely reloads.

Why is this happening? I should be able to change `PUBLIC_URL` to anything with a slash at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the bundle JS file was being cached by the browser so it never has a new hash for that equality check.

By default webpack-dev-server does not cache the bundle file.